# How to implement a SVM on a distributed platform like Hadoop

Tags: svm, optimization, parallel-computing

I am trying to implement a SVM on a distributed computing paltform. More generally, I am asking how to solve a minimax problem distributively.

[image]

I can not find a way to tackle the `X'X` because computing an entry in this matrix will require two training examples. And this leads to the problem of dividing the input into chunks in a typical distributed platform.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem or know any source that I can refer to?

Comment: The SMO algorithm for estimating SVMs only works with two examples at a time. I'm not sure if that solves your problem or not (hence the comment), but I would recommend looking into it.

Comment: Actually it works with two constraint variables at a time. But it stills need the X'X matrix

Comment: can you use gradient descent?